# Add logic to a gitlab pipeline to deploy AWS or Azure resources using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, terraform, gitlab

I have a pipeline that is pulling in data from a DynamoDB table. Depending on what variables are pulled in, I want it to run a pipeline that creates either Azure or AWS resources. Is this possible? What is the best approach? If you have resources on further reading, I would appreciate it!

I am conducting research and trying to come up with possible solutions that adds logic to the upstream pipeline.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort your DB data with a column which will identify the AWS/Azure data.

1. In GitLab create a Terraform `provider.tf` file with two providers AWS and Azurerm

#Provider.tf file

```py
provider "aws" {
    features{}
    metadata_host= "AWS https url connection"
    Clientcreadentials = ""
    etc
    etc
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
    metadata_host= "AWS https url connection"
    Clientcreadentials = ""
    etc
    etc
}
```

2. Create a `main.tf` file

#Main.tf

```py
# See [Terraform AWS Resources documentation][1]
resource "aws_resourcegroups_group" "example" {
    provider = aws
    name = dynamotable.AWS.name
}

# See [Terraform Azure Resources documentation][2]
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    provider = azurerm
    name = dynamotable.Azurerm.name
}


  [1]: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/resourcegroups_group
  [2]: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group
```